# Let $p(x) = ax^2+2bx+c$ be a quadratic form, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are real numbers. Find supremum of $p(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $p(x) = ax^2+2bx+c$ be a quadratic form, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are real numbers. how to find the supremum of $p(x)$ where $x$ belongs to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: To what corresponds the supremum of a function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $a > 0$ then $\text{sup}\{p(x)\}=+\infty$. If $a<0$ then you could find the vertex of the parabola $y=p(x)$ ($\text{sup}\{p(x)\}$ is the $y$th coordinate of the vertex). Also, if $a=b=0$ then $\text{sup}\{p(x)\}=c$. Finally, if $a=0$ and $b \neq 0$ then $\text{sup}\{p(x)\}=+\infty$.

**Update:** If $a<0$ then we have a parabola opened down. So, the highest point of the parabola is its vertex. The $x$th coordinate of the vertex is $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$ (according to Vieta's theorem if $x_1,x_2$ are the roots of the quadratic form then $x_1+x_2=-\frac{b}{a}$ and the $x$th coordinate of the vertex is $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$).

Comment: You are not serious with the last $-\infty$, are you?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: :) You are right, sorry

Comment: can you please elaborate the case when $a$ < $0$

Comment: You need to complete the square.

Comment: @liesel: I updated my post.